# 64Bit Page tables are too big?

Tags: paging, virtual-memory

64bit virtual address covers 18446744073709551616 bytes. with a 4KB page sized we'll need 4503599627370496 page table entries where each entry is 8 bytes .

so we'll have :  (4503599627370496 * 8 ) = 36028797018963968 bytes.

and every process has it's own page table. this is too large for a page table. i was wondering how the system handles this ?

Answer (score 0):

They don't. Most current systems don't actually allow processes to use anywhere near that amount of memory.  Usually, there is a limit of something like 64TB of memory maximum that any process can use.  Of course, in any practical situation, very bad things will happen before anything gets anywhere near using that much memory.

Additionally, there is no need to keep page entries for sections of address space that have not been referenced by a process yet, so even if you want to allow processes to access the full range of memory addresses, you don't have to fill in page entries until that memory is actually accessed.